# Drawing custom 3d shapes

Tags: c++, cinder

I am attempting to create a custom object using Cinder C++ on windows with Visual Studio. I am hoping to find a solution that allows you to point to a object with BatchRef object, and which can be used in the same way as any other BatchRef.

I have already tried searching through the official websites tutorials and documentation, and while it does an excellent job of listing all the classes, functions, etc, it does a exceedingly slim job of covering the usage of most of those, with only the return type and arguments listed.

Ideally, we could call the custom shape something like myShape and it could be used in the following manner in my App::draw() override: (with mShader already defined someplace else)

```
gl::BatchRef bRef;
gl::pushModelMatrix();
bRef = gl::Batch::create( myShape() , mShader );
bRef -> draw();
gl::popModelMatrix();
```

If the documentation has instructions for this, feel free to point me that way. I was unable to find it, but that does not mean that it does not exist.

Comment: [The documentation says](https://libcinder.org/docs/classcinder_1_1gl_1_1_batch.html#public-static-functions) that you can create a BatchRef from either a VboMeshRef or a geom::Source. Have you tried to create one of those?

Comment: I am not sure how to use either of those classes to create my custom object. Looking at each of their documentation does not show me enough to figure it out on my own, and I don't see any examples in the sample code they provide.

Comment: Though, I've some experience in OpenGL, I haven't any concerning Cinder. Out of curiosity, I googled ["cinder vbomesh example"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cinder+vbomesh+example). IMHO, I found some promising links with code. As you didn't describe your custom shape in detail, please, feel free to look yourself.